# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function posix_getgrgid()

Tags: php

In PHP I am getting the following error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   posix_getgrgid()

Following PHP code is throwing the error.

```
<?php

$a = posix_getgrgid(0);
var_dump($a);

?>
```

PHP version: 7.4.5
OS: Windows 10

How can I fix this?

Comment: Posix = Unix/Linux. You can't use this function on Windows, and whatever you're intending to do will likely have to be _vastly_ different on Windows as opposed to Linux.

Comment: I guess, you are right. Do we have a Windows alternative?